# How do I make the compiler warn me about missing return value?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-warnings

So i just wasted an hour trying to figure out why my program crashed. As it happens, i forgot to put in the return statement of my function.

the function was about as follows:

```
structType name(2 parameters){
     .....
}
```

I am used to getting warnings, that the return statement is missing.
Why didn't it do so here and how can i turn that feature on?

[I code in C]
EDIT: using GCC

Comment: *"How do I make the compiler warn me"* **Which** compiler?

Comment: I am using GCC from the MingW distribution

Comment: What is your compilation command now? Please create [mcve] of your compilation command.

Comment: I normally use -Wall to enable "most of" the compiler warnings. Does this help?

Comment: The 'classical' flags to enable warnings are `-Wall -Wextra`. Unrelated, but I also suggest using `-std=c++?? -pedantic-errors` (put version instead of `??`) to make GCC reject nonportable code.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the [gcc docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html)?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Option `-std=c++??` should probably be `-std=c??`, right?

Comment: @Gerhardh Silly me, didn't look at the tags.

Comment: Thank you all for the quick response. -Wall helped a lot!

Comment: What about the fine documentation is unclear? It's well structured

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason *why* there is no warning from omitted `return` statement is that it isn't "wrong" - the C standard explicitly allows it, and such a program is well-defined; only, you're not to use the return value if none was actually returned.

Whatever the warnings that are emitted by default are mostly those that the C standard names as constraint violations - a conforming compiler must diagnose these. Hence, using `-pedantic-errors` or `-std=c17` or similar is not going to do *anything at all*, because it makes the compiler being more pedantic (i.e. more diagnostics-conforming) about following the C standard which says that this is OK after all.

In GCC the warning can be controlled with `-Wreturn-type`, which will enabled by `-Wall` too. (Why aren't you using `-Wall`?!):

```
% echo 'int foo() { }' > noreturn.c && gcc -c -Wreturn-type noreturn.c
noreturn.c: In function ‘foo’:
noreturn.c:1:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 int foo() { }
 ^~~
```

Comment: I have never heard of -Wall to be honest. I have just tried it and its absolutely amazing. Exactly what I wanted! So many Issues were spottet, that would have given me headaches for hours!

Comment: @RIJIK about time then! Please consider also `-Wextra` and even `-Werror` :D